# Timer based quiz implementation in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a quiz game in PHP, in which user is presented with questions which user needs to answer it exactly in 15 minutes.  During those 15 minutes that question will be shown as 'taken' to all other users. If user fails to solve it in 15 mins then that question become available to all users again.

I've build a db structure as:

```
tbl_Question
pkQuestionId
question

tbl_UserQuestion
pkUserQuestionId
fkQuestionId
fkUserId
timeStamp

tbl_User
pkUserId
```

The approach I tried is to insert a record in `tbl_UserQuestion` if user want to solve it, with time stamp. Then fetch all the questions from `tbl_Question` which are not in `tbl_UserQuestion`.

I'm stuck on how to show questions to other users if initial user is failed to solve it in 15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bit flag to determine if the question was solved or not into the userQuestion table and then in your query to see which questions are still available for other users, you see if there is a userQuestion that hasn't been answered (0) and has been more than 15 minutes since the time stamp. You'd also need to make sure it wasn't then answered by someone after. If you see that case then the answer wasn't completed within 15 minutes. You would just need to update that record within 15 minutes to put answered (1) and then you would know that question isn't available anymore. The other option would be to just delete the record from the userQuestion table if the user fails (unless you want to know that they failed)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm stuck on query, what kind of query do I need to present question to all other users if particular question's entry in already present in tbl_UserQuestion. One more thing, how can I update time stamp automatically? I don't want to use cron job

Comment: something like `SELECT FROM tbl_Question AS Q LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_UserQuestion AS UQ on UQ.fkQuestionId = Q.pkQuestionId WHERE UQ.fkQuestionId IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT UQ2.fkQuestionId FROM tbl_UserQuestion AS UQ2 WHERE datediff(mi,  GETDATE(), UQ2.timeStamp) < 15 OR UQ2.answered = 1`  I'm not sure if the syntax is perfect on that since i typed it in there but basically you just want to eliminate things with answered = 1 or ones within 15 minutes. As for updating time stamp i'm not sure what you mean. why would you update it?